# Why does it keep saying initialize variable?

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is the code I wrote. I need to initialize a variable called verificationID for later use. But I keep getting a red squiggly line with the text -

1. Final variable verificationID must be initialized
2. Non-nullable instance field vdi must be initialized.

Is this not how you initialize - final [datatype] [name]

I am brand new to flutter and could use any help!

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
enum NumberVerification {
  SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE,
  SHOW_OTP_FORM_STATE,
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String verificationID;
  String vdi;
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because `flutter` and `dart language` are `null safety`. It means you should initialize your variables, and there will be `no error` regarding this in `runtime`. So when you write `dart` codes you must initialize them as follows:

1- In some cases you can `init` value directly as follows:

```
final String verificationID = 'value';
```

2- Or you can get the value from `constructor` of class.

```
final String verificationID;

LoginScreen(this.verificationID);
```

3- And also, you can declare that you will initialize the value `later`. This way you `guarantee` that you will initialize the value, so you should use it wisely.

```
late String verificationID;

verificationID = 'value';
```

4- Lastly, you may declare a value as `nullable`. This way, you don't need to initialize the variable directly.

```
String? verificationID;
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation to each of your examples since we are talking about a beginner which, very likely, does not understand the different types of syntax and what it actually means. :)

Comment: @julemand101 Added the explanations :)

Comment: Your fourth example only works for non-final variables.

Comment: @Nitrodon I was not using a text editor to help fastly. I have edited it as you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All variables in Dart are getting the value `null` if nothing else are specified. This is a problem in your case since both `verificationID` and `vdi` are specified as non-nullable types (no `?` after the type name). So Dart complains about this problem.

Another problem is your `final` variable which also should be provided a value since this is a read-only variable which can only be assigned a value when initialized.

You therefore need to do:

- Change the types to allow `null`.
- Or, provide default value other than `null`.
- Or, make a constructor of your class which gives values to your variables. These values can come from parameters to the constructor.